# How do I perform a rename on only one "from" in a Gradle Copy task?

Tags: gradle, copy, task, rename

I am trying to copy from multiple "from" locations on a single Gradle Copy task. For one of those - and only one - I want to also perform a rename operation.

This code works:

```
task dist(type: Copy) {
    from task1
    rename { filename -> filename.replace '-all.jar', '.jar' }
    from task2 { exclude "lib" }
    into "${projectDir}/dist"
}
```

But the renaming operation also affects `task2`. I tried doing it this way:

```
task dist(type: Copy) {
    from task1 { rename { filename -> filename.replace '-all.jar', '.jar' } }
    from task2 { exclude "lib" }
    into "${projectDir}/dist"
}
```

But it does not do the renaming operation. The exclude operation on `task2` works as expected. Is it possible? Am I missing something in the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Someone posted the solution here and deleted it before I could accept/reply, so I'm posting the correct form here for future reference:

```
task dist(type: Copy) {
    from (task1) { rename { filename -> filename.replace '-all.jar', '.jar' } }
    from (task2) { exclude "lib" }
    into "${projectDir}/dist"
}
```

Thanks, Opalo!